# Can Helm chart copy the manifest from another Helm Chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have question regarding the Helm Chart. I'm curious whether this scenario can be implemented. I have Helm Chart #1 which holds deployment resource. The Helm Chart #2 should copy the manifest file (like a template) from Helm Chart #1, and modify some values (such as label) dynamically.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Not really – you might be able to make it happen with something like a [post renderer](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering), but not in a wrapper chart – but you can install the same chart multiple times with different names and `-f more-values.yaml` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Helm Template and override the values using -f values.yaml!